# How to grab specifc libraries from my boost/lib folder?

Tags: c++, dll, boost, portability

I've compiled Boost and it works just fine. I would like to to copy specific .dll's and .libs into my project for deployment. The problem is I'm having a hard time finding which packages contain the libraries I need. I've looked around but haven't seen any documentation on what's actually inside the compiled libraries.

For instance, if I wanted to use boost:asio and boost::prt_vector in my project, which .dll/.libs should I copy over?

The entire library folder is over 1.2 GB so I'd rather not use the entire thing. I'm using Windows, vs2008.

Any ideas?

Comment: boost::prt_vector is header only, you don't need a lib or dll for it.

Comment: Most of boost is header only. SO you may not need to bundle any libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you deploying your application as an executable or as a project to be compiled by the user? If it is the former, you shouldn't need to send static libraries, as they're linked into your executable. If you build Boost libraries as dynamic libraries, you will need them of course.

But if you're deploying your app as something to be compiled, or if you have Boost DLLs, then as martiall said, you should use [BCP](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: "*And Boost doesn't have any DLLs*" It does if you run bjam with `runtime-link=dynamic`; there's nothing inherent in Boost that makes its libraries static-only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bcp which is bundled in Boost

[BCP Docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html)